# Manage Client Servers without joining domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

Forgive me if the logic of this question is incorrect in anyway, I'm new to windows server administration (always willing to learn new stuff though :))

We have clients who we deploy our software to and managing all these servers becomes a hassle especially with firewall updates, config changes, new software deployments (not our own, we use a CI/CD tool for that) but admin tools such as Heidi or Oracle SQL Developer etc.

I want a tool that would allow me to push these sorts of changes without needing to manually make them on all servers. I am aware I could possibly utilise ActiveDirectory for this, however, this would require setting up AD and joining any new clients to our domain (I think? I'm not overly familiar with AD). I am also aware that I can join these servers to the Server Manager of our Operations server, however, again, it doesn't seem that there is a way for me to push applications and config changes to all servers in a pool (correct me if I'm wrong)

So my question is basically:

Is there a way for me to manage external clients servers without them joining our AD domain (which I'm reluctant to do because our AD is local to one machine and is not configured)

FYI our "operations" machine (i.e. the one where I will push changes from) is running Windows Server 2012-r however, if need be, I can move to a Server2016. Secondly, the remote machines all run 2016

-- Odatia

Comment: Solutions would depend on if you had VPN or other network connectivity in place, or if you would need "agents" on the remote machines to connect back for connectivity. Also, it sound like you are a third party software developer or similar. Do you own the remote servers, or are they owned separately?

Comment: @CoryKnutson you're right, we are a software house, hosted and on-premise. Servers are owned by our customers. We have full access rights to the servers. I can take either the VPN route or the "agents" on the remotes, however,  I would prefer the latter due to ease of configuration...

Answer (score 1):

Any MSP tool could be used there.

We use nable from solarwind and you can do those task easilly and got remotecontrol options too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using PowerShell DSC or another configuration management platform such as Puppet or Chef.

[Powershell DSC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview)
[Puppet](https://puppet.com/)